# Django- Why I am getting this Programming Error

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

Django- Why I am getting this Programming Error When I have not declared shop_product variable anywhere .
Please help [Click here to view error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FNRA.png)

please refer to this image of error

Comment: and please read the `why-not-upload-images` https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. In addition to Bear Brown's recommandation, I'd also suggest you read [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`shop_product` is the name of the database table for the model `Product` in the application `shop`.

Most likely cause for this error is that you didn't apply database migrations, or, if you did, that you didn't add the application `shop` to your `INSTALLED_APPS`.

**Update:**

According to one of your comments, you are trying to use SQLite, which you cannot use on Heroku, see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3

But it seems you figured that out because according to the settings of your app, you are using PostgreSQL, but you have not applied your migration.

Migrations are created once with `manage.py makemigrations`, but you have to apply them on every database, i.e. both on your local dev environment and on the database your application running on Heroku uses. For the latter, try this:

```
heroku run python manage.py
```

Comment: kindly check my page it is not working https://kharidarikaro.herokuapp.com/shop but https://kharidarikaro.herokuapp.com/shop/contact is working fine please help me

Comment: even django admin is not working in that page after logging I am getting ProgrammingError at /admin/login/
relation "auth_user" does not exist
LINE 1: ...user"."is_active", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "auth_user... this error

Comment: Thanks a lot now it worked. you are such a nice guy.

Comment: Glad I could help! If my answer solved your problem, please accept it by clicking the checkmark

Comment: Sure and I need one more help when I am uploading the products image on database The database automatically changes the name of image why it happening can you tell me please? just becuase of this image is not displaying on my page

Answer (score 0):

From the partial SQL query in the image it seems that "shop_product" is a table.
Note:

```
LINE 1: ... "shop_product"."id" FROM "shop_product"
```

1. Check your models if you have ShopProduct model, and check if you have migrations are updated.
2. Check if you have ManyToMany fields that might create that table, and also check if migrations are up to date.

Comment: Everything is working fine when I run the project in local server but it is not working when I deployed it to heroku .

Comment: I am using SQLite as a database on heroku. is it possible that I am getting that error because I am using SQLite?

Comment: kindly check my page it is not working https://kharidarikaro.herokuapp.com/shop/ but https://kharidarikaro.herokuapp.com/shop/contact is working fine please help me